# Relationship between Poisson arrival rate and Exponential inter-arrival rate

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

A poisson distribution has a lambda 1.5 per minute. I would like to know as to how would i use this for the lambda in exponential distribution? Would both the lambda values be the same?